# Выборка предыдущих значений по условию в другом столбце?

Tags: sql, oracle, оконные-функции

В таблице имеется большое количество отрицательных значений в перемешку со значениями 0, например:

```
2015-02-24  -11213.99
2015-02-25          0
2015-06-18  -58832.61
2015-06-19          0
2015-08-18   -55404.6
2015-08-19          0
```

Каким образом можно выбрать именно значения дат предыдущих 0?

Например, предыдущее значение -11213,99 соответсвенно дата 24.02.2015.

Я попробовал использовать оконную функцию `lag`:

```
SELECT lag(test_date, 1) over (partition by test_num order by test_date)
FROM test_table
WHERE test_num = 0;
```

Однако выводится только выборка именно значений с 0.

Comment: Оконные функции применяются к выходному набору, т.е. после `WHERE test_num = 0`. Следует выполнить этот запрос без WHERE в CTE, а во внешнем запросе уже применить WHERE. Причём этот запрос сработает исключительно в случае, когда нет двух подряд записей с нулём.

Comment: @Akina мб выбрать лагом не только дату, но и предыдущее значение. а потом отфильтровать по текущему = 0 и предыдущему > 0

Comment: Покажите требуемый результат запроса для показанных исходных данных. Что и в каких колонках надо получить?

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте так - аналитической функцией [LAST_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LAST_VALUE.html#GUID-A646AF95-C8E9-4A67-87BA-87B11AEE7B79) получите последнее значение столбца с датой, но не учитывая нули в столбце с числом:

```
select dat old, num, 
    last_value (case when num != 0 then dat end ignore nulls) over (order by dat) new
from t
```

Результат (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5eda2fd89fa36698196001564aaf1323)):

```
OLD               NUM NEW       
---------- ---------- ----------
2015-02-23  -11800.93 2015-02-23
2015-02-24  -11213.99 2015-02-24
2015-02-25          0 2015-02-24
2015-06-18  -58832.61 2015-06-18
2015-06-19          0 2015-06-18
2015-06-20          0 2015-06-18
2015-08-18   -55404.6 2015-08-18
2015-08-19          0 2015-08-18
```